# Chrome to save HTML content

Tags: html, google-chrome

I would like to get the company details from ASX website:

http://www.asx.com.au/asx/share-price-research/company/ACB/details

I use 'Save As' in Chrome to save it as an html file. When I inspect the file in Notepad, I can't find any data/informationn that shown in Chrome.

Any idea how this happen?

Comment: A few years later there is an API at the ASX, eg https://www.asx.com.au/asx/1/company/ACB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is probably due to javascript isn't executed in source. Use inspect element when page was loaded. Right click on page, then click inspect element. After that right click on  tag and -> Edit as HTML. Copy code to your notepad.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `"Webpage complete"` while saving that page.

This will give you all the information which you are looking for.